# Moving to the end of the last word on a line

Tags: cursor-movement, whitespace

There are commands to distinguish between the beginning of a line (`0`) and the beginning of the first word of the line (`^`), basically ignoring leading whitespace.  But I can only find one way to move to the end of a line (`$`), including whitespace, much like `0`, but no way to move to the end of the last word.

Is there an end-of-line equivalent to `^`, which ignores trailing whitespace?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`g_` will to go to the last non-blank character of the line

For more help see `:h g_`

Answer (score 4):

- `$` or `<End>` - goes to end of line
- `g_` - goes to last non blank of line
- `g$` or `g<End>` (both take a count) - goes to end of last screen n-1'th line
- `<Ctrl><End>` (takes a count) - goes to end of absolute n'th line

Answer (score 2):

Yes, see `:h g_`

```
g_          To the last non-blank character of the line and
            [count - 1] lines downward |inclusive|.
```